# Resignation after two months

Tags: resignation

I started out with big MNC right after my B-school which was my first job. Due to some circumstances I resigned and joined other MNC after a gap of 2 months. Now, my earlier organization's general manager has called me back to rejoin. I intend to do so. I have received confirmation over mail but not the offer letter.

I would like to resign from my current organization on good note. I need help to proceed ahead with resignation. I don't know what should I say in resignation letter.

Comment: Are you still in a probation period?

Comment: Don't resign until you get the offer letter. An email means nothing. If you resign and then they don't send the offer letter, you end up being the guy who resigned from *two* consecutive jobs within 2 months, and as a bonus, you would be unemployed. Good luck trying to find another job after that.

Comment: That aside, I find it extremely hard to believe that a GM would rehire someone who joined right after college and then resigned after 2 months. What exactly did you do in those 2 months that makes you so "irreplaceable"? (This is not a rhetorical question, I am really curious to know.)

Comment: @Happy The way I read the question is that the unemployment gap between jobs was 2 months, not that their stay at the previous job was that short.

Answer (score 0):

1. Carefully study your current contract. Make sure you know what the notice periods, probation periods + rules. Make sure you understand any immediate dead lines, i.e. does your probation end after 60 days, 90 days, etc.?
2. Don't communicate ANYTHING until you have the offer letter in hand and you are happy with it
3. The resignation letter should be short and to the point: "I'm resigning my position with you. My last day at work will be ..."
4. The actual reason for your departure should be discussed with your manager face to face. It's best you resign in a face to face meeting. You can hand over the letter at that point as well, but you need to start with a real meeting. Explain why you are leaving. Be honest. Be appreciative of your manager and your current job.
5. Have reasonable expectations about the outcome. The fact of the matter is that you leave your current job after two months, which puts them in an awkward position. Chances are you will end up on their do-not-rehire list no matter what you do.